# Checkbox checked triggers multiple required fields

Tags: jquery, forms

I've created a jQuery form with a checkbox that, when checked, will reveal a dropdown menu. However, if that same checkbox is checked, in addition to revealing the dropdown menu, I need it to also require that the Discussion textarea field be completed. Here's what I have so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
* { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 96%; }
label { width: 10em; float: left; }
label.error { float: none; color: red; padding-left: .5em; vertical-align: top; }
p { clear: both; }
.submit { margin-left: 12em; }
em { font-weight: bold; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align: top; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#fourthselection").change(function(){      
            var showOrHide =$(this).is(':checked');         
                $("#togg").toggle(showOrHide);      
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#serviceForm").validate();
    });
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<form id="serviceForm" action="#" onSubmit="required(this);" method="POST"> 
<input name="orgid" type="hidden" value="000001" /> 
<input name="retURL" type="hidden" value="#" />
<label for="company">* Company</label><br />  
<input id="company" class="required" maxlength="80" name="company" size="80" type="text" /><br />
<br />
<label for="name">* Name</label><br />
<input id="name" class="required" maxlength="80" name="name" size="80" type="text" /><br />
<br />
<label for="email">Email</label>  <br />
<input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="80" type="text" /><br />
<br />
<label for="phone">Phone</label><br />
<input id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /><br />
<br />
<br />
Make selection?<br />
<input id="firstselection" name="firstselection" type="checkbox" value="1" /> First selection <br />
<input id="secondselection" name="secondselection" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Second selection<br />
<input id="thirdselection" name="thirdselection" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Third selection <br />
<input id="fourthselection" name="fourthselection" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Fourth selection <br />
<span id="togg" style="display:none">
If fourth selection, please make a selection?  
<select  id="fourthchoices" name="fourthchoices" title="Fourth selection choices">
<option value="">--Please Select One--</option>
<option value="Choice A">Choice A</option>
<option value="Choice B">Choice B</option>
<option value="Choice C">Choice C</option>
<option value="Choice D">Choice D</option>
<option value="Choice E">Choice E</option>
<option value="Choice F">Choice F</option>
<option value="Choice G">Choice G</option>
<option value="Choice H">Choice H</option>
</select><br>
</span>
<input id="selection" name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Fifth selection<br />
<input id="sixthselection" name="sixthselection" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Sixth selection<br />
<input id="otherselection" name="otherselection" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Other 
<br />
<br />
<span id="togg2" style="display:inline">
<label for="description">Description</label> <br />
(if Fourth selection, please include more information)<br />
<textarea name="description" id="description" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea><br />
<br />
<br />
</span>
<input name="submit" type="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; please take some time to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). If someone's answer has answered your question, please don't forget to click on the check mark next to their [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/171243).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
$("#fourthselection").change(function(){      
    $("#togg").toggle(this.checked);
    $("#description").toggleClass("required");
});
$("#serviceForm").validate();
```

And here is [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/mjRGY).

Use native javasript whenever possible, like; you can access checkboxes status with `this.checked`. And it'll be very good if you prepare your question on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or some equivalent website.

Comment: Emre - Thanks for the answer. One more thing... I'm trying to configure it so that the dropdown associated with the fourth checkbox is required. So, in summary, when the fourth checkbox is check, the dropdown is required as well as the Discussion textarea. The latter is already functioning properly, thanks to your previous answer. Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks again.